# Mac-like text rendering on Windows?

Tags: windows, text, rendering, macos

I'm trying to figure out how to render text on Windows with the same display as Mac rendered text, e.g: http://igadgetlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/11.png (That picture is not perfect, but it showcases the neat anti aliasing that Mac has)

I've looked at GDI++/Freetype, and it seems too unstable and it has a lack of documentation. If anyone has any suggestions, that'd be great.
The reason I am asking is because I am trying to make a writing program where text readability and text display are two important factors.

Thanks

Comment: Didn't Apple license some proprietary font-hinting technology from Adobe? If a commercial solution is acceptable to you, you might look into that. Also, what version of Windows are you targeting?

Comment: I don't know much about Apple's software - I haven't heard anything about them licensing an Adobe technology at least. Unfortunately a commercial solution is not viable, I'm just trying to create something I can use instead of Word... I hate Word. Targeting XP - 7, maybe not XP, in that case, Vista - 7.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this Coding Horror article is related [http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html).

Comment: Yeah, I've read that article. I mostly agree, although I think the font rendering a program should use depends on the program's purpose. E.g I would prefer pixel bounded font rendering for coding, but Apple's way of doing things for reading/writing in programs such as Word. I think for the app I am currently writing this is especially important - I am trying to get a layout/design that is similar to that of Writer's: http://www.iawriter.com/

Comment: That text was rendered with ClearType anti-aliasing.  ClearType was invented by Microsoft.  Not getting ClearType on Windows requires some effort, it is completely unclear what you did wrong.  I'm guessing you actually do but are simply using an ugly font.

Comment: That may be (the thing about me using an ugly font), but I know the font that Writer uses, and it's expensive (for me at least). I'm looking for a font, but I haven't found a good, free alternative.

Answer (score 12):

The solution lies in using [gdipp](http://code.google.com/p/gdipp/) to override the default font-rendering engine in Windows. Just download the latest package from their [Google project page](http://code.google.com/p/gdipp/) and double click to install it.

It will automatically get installed as a service. If you don't notice any change in the way fonts render, open **Run** -> Type **services.msc** -> Right click **gdipp** -> Click **Start**.

You may need to restart your computer once for all programs to start respecting gdipp's rendering engine.

**EDIT: Alternatively, look at [MacType](http://code.google.com/p/mactype/). It's a user-space application that won't require being run as a service. It works with Chrome as well.**

Comment: +1 for MacType. Didn't know that little gem. Seems to work much better than gdipp so far, and more stable.